# How to have a div scrolled to the bottom automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I am making a chat-like interface which can be seen here (best viewed in Chrome right now):

http://qas.im/web/sms.php

The temporary username:password is **temp_guest:password**

My problem is that when you click one of the chats, it doesnt automatically scroll to the bottom when I use this code:

```
$(".messages").attr({ scrollTop: $(".messages").attr("scrollHeight") });
```

What could be wrong? The messages div has a css of:

```
.messages {
    height:400px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

For people who are wondering: Page isnt HTML validated yet but I will be cleaning it up soon. Most of the page is auto-generated which is challenging to make the code look pretty ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jQuery 1.6 or later, use `prop` instead of `attr`.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/PNwj3/

Answer (score 1):

I found two issues.

The first is that you were trying to set all `.message` DIVs to the height of the first DIV, so if the first DIV was hidden, it would never work.

The second was that jQuery's attr function is only for node attributes.

This method works better, and scrolls all the divs correctly:

```
$(".messages").each(function(idx, node) { node.scrollTop = node.scrollHeight; });
```

Alternatively, you can improve performance by using this selector:

```
$(".messages:visible").each(function(idx, node) { node.scrollTop = node.scrollHeight; });
```

Which works on visible message nodes.

Comment: Yes, I also just realized that and fixed up my code so when each one is visible, I will use the code given in the working example that FishBasketGordo gave us to automatically bring it down.